# Do-while or while loop that will keep taking an input from user but will terminate after I input the string "exit" (case insensitive) in c language

Tags: c, string, loops, do-while, string-comparison

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    char out[] = "exit";

    do {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", str);

        // some if else statement here 

    } while (toupper(str[3]) != toupper(out[3]));
}
```

I put the index 3 because if I put the index 0 there, the code will terminate if the entered string starts with letter e. I tried the while loop but it does not work for me. Also I want to print a prompt message that says "detected terminate keyword" after entering the word "exit" and then terminates the loop.

You will also notice the `toupper()` function. I used it there because I want my loop to be case insensitive, so regarless of lowercase or uppercase or combination of both, the loop should terminate when the word "exit" is entered.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please [edit] and fix it. Hint: read the chapter dealing with strings in your learning material. You need the [`strcmp`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function here.

Comment: BTW : `while (toupper(str[3]) != toupper(out[3])` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? The obvious syntax errors or the complete absence of code checking the input vs the contents of `out`? Are you asking how to compare strings in C or what?

Answer (score 1):

`toupper(str[3]) != toupper(out[3])` will compare the upper case 4th letter of `str` and `out`, so the loop will iterate till `str[3]` is `'T'`.  You want to use `strcasecmp(str, out)` instead. Remember to `#include <strings.h>`.

Comment: Thank you! This one really helped! However, I want to print a statement before terminating the loop, how do I do that? Like if I entered the word "exit", it should print ```"Detected terminate keyword. Goodbye!"``` then terminate the program.

Comment: Add the print statement after the loop.  If you want it in the loop you can change your do-while loop to  `for(;;) { ... if(!strcasecmp(str, out)) { printf('Detected..."); break; } }`

Answer (score 1):

> *I put the index 3 because if I put the index 0 there, the code will terminate if the entered string starts with letter `e`*

Exactly, and the code:

```
while (toupper(str[3]) != toupper(out[3])
```

Suffers from the same problem, any input with a `t` as its 4th character index 3 will match and the loop will end, you are comparing a specific character of the string, not the string itself. You can use `strcasecmp` to assess if the input is indeed `exit` and ignore casing.

Furthermore using `%s` specifier is not good, you run the risk of overrunning the destination buffer. You should use a width, `%99s` for a 100 characters buffer to leave space for the nul byte, if possible consider using `fgets` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    char str[100];

    char out[] = "exit";

    do {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf(" %99s", str); // space before specifier to clean leading whitespaces

        // some if else statement here 

    } while (strcasecmp(str, out) != 0);

    puts("Detected terminate keyword. Goodbye!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- it is confusing for a function `isPalindrome()` to return `0` for true.
- to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values, a `char` argument to `toupper` should be cast as `(unsigned char)`.
- the test for the `exit` keyword is incorrect. You exit if the fourth letter is a `t` or a `T`. You should use `strcasecmp` to test for the `exit` word.
- `scanf("%s", str)` has potential undefined behavior if the user enters a word with more than 99 bytes. Use `scanf("%99s", str)` and test the return value: it must be `1` for a successful conversion.
- instead of a confusing `do` / `while` loop, use a `for (;;)` loop (also known as *for ever* loop), and test for 2 exit conditions: `scanf()` failure to read a word and reading the word `exit`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPalindrome(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (toupper((unsigned char)str[i]) != toupper((unsigned char)str[len - i - 1]))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char str[100];

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1)
            break;
        if (!strcasecmp(str, "exit"))
            break;

        if (isPalindrome(str)) {
            printf("%s is a palindrome!\n\n", str);
        } else {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome!\n\n", str);
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is `do/while`  confusing?

Comment: @0___________: Because the condition is at the end and newbies consistently and incorrectly run the body of the loop instead of testing the condition where appropriate and exiting the loop with a `break` statement. There were 2 instances of this mistake in the last half hour.  Even savvy programmers get bitten by this, scanning for `while (c != '\n');` will show many potentially infinite loops `do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n');`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *removeLastChar(char *str, char ch)
{
    size_t len;
    if(str)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        if(str[len - 1] == ch) str[len -1] = 0;
    }
    return str;
}

char *strlwr(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    if(str)
    {
        while(*wrk)
        {
            *wrk = tolower((unsigned char)*wrk);
            wrk++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char str[100];
    const char *out = "exit";

    int x = 0;

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        if(!fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) break;
        removeLastChar(str, '\n');

        printf("You entered: \"%s\"\n:", str);

     } while (strcmp(strlwr(str), out)); 
}
```